# How to properly looping movement of an object

Tags: movement

I would like to create an intelligent (universal) class to looping movement object, like sliding doors, etc.

I've thought to declare two vectors:

From 
To

And a Speed variable.

Then looping. I don't know how to check when current position is >= then To and looping reverse, considering that you can have starting position (x or y or z) greater then arriving position.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve this by abstracting your loop phase from the position, something like this:

```
phase = phase + deltaTime/travelTime;

// Here I use a cosine wave to get a nice ease-in and -out.
// You could use a triangle wave instead for linear motion.
weight = 0.5 * (1 - cos(phase * PI))

position = lerp(From, To, weight);
```

Here when `phase` is `0`, you're at `From`, about to start moving toward `To`. At `0.5`, you're halfway from `From` to `To`. At `phase = 1.0`, the object has arrived at `To` and is about to turn around and return to `From`. At `1.5`, it's halfway back to `From`. And at `2.0` the cycle repeats (you could take `phase` modulo 2 for the same effect).